# .htaccess replace question marks and slashes from URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to do this by using .htaccess

Redirect: `http://example.com/en/signup?type=something`

To: `http://example.com/snapshots/en_signup_type=something.html`

Basically, convert all slashes and question marks to underscores and appending `.html`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to do, there are actually a few more steps than I thought.

1. Replace all slashes with underscores, `RewriteRule ^(.*)\/(.*)$ $1_$2 [R=301,L]`, based on the number of slashes we have, it will redirect the same amount of times, one redirection will convert one slash to one underscore.

`http://example.com/en/signup?type=something` -> `http://example.com/en_signup?type=something`

2. Convert the query string (change question mark to underscore)

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/snapshots/$1_%{QUERY_STRING}.html? [P,L]`

The question mark after .html is to prevent the query string to be appended again.